# Payment using messenger bots

Tags: facebook, message, bots

I have one requirement in which I need to develop Facebook messenger bots and implement payment for product from bots.

Has anyone experience with payment with bots and its approval by Facebook?

Answer (score 0):

As I know currently it only has a receipt structured message that you can use for sending receipt. But there is no any API supports for the payment, you could either make a series of messages between the bot and customers by using postback, but it's very inefficient and stupid, also insecure. So I recommend using an external link that customers can click it and go to your payment system.

Comment: Thats what we have planned to have one web page integrated with payment stuff and open in browser on click of "Buy Now".

Answer (score 0):

I have developed a bot that has integration with Stripe Payments (which is really fantastic btw). I created a WebView that redirects to my payment processing page. I didn't have any issues with the approval. All I did was send them a demo of how I get card information and showed them that I'm not storing any specific payment information because stripe hides the actual info and gives me a token to process a payment.

I find Bot approval in Facebook is stringent but straightforward as long as you give them the information they need. That means giving them a DEMO on how you're going to collect information and make sure that everything is clear.

Our terms and condition also have some payment terms (cancellation, refund, etc). Although they never checked it, I would highly suggest to clearly state these items on the T and C - and of course, make sure they tick a box specifying they agreed to such terms.

Good luck!